# Consulta Compleja

Tags: sql

Tengo esta consulta en la que me gustaria insertar los campos de nombre y apellido que tengo en otra tabla con nombre empleados, como puedo hacer un inner join para unir la tabla donde tengo estos datos? Los campos claves en ambas tablas son "empleado",

```
WITH EntradaSalida (Empleado, Fecha, FechaHoras, Num) AS
    (
        SELECT 
        Numeroempleado, CONVERT(DATE, Fechahora), Fechahora, ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(PARTITION BY Numeroempleado, CONVERT(DATE, Fechahora) ORDER BY Fechahora)    
        FROM AltasDiarias
    ) 
    SELECT 
    E.Fecha, E.Empleado, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, E.FechaHoras, S.FechaHoras)) / 60 [Horas],
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, E.FechaHoras, S.FechaHoras)) % 60 [Minutos] 
    FROM EntradaSalida E
    INNER JOIN EntradaSalida S ON S.Empleado=E.Empleado 
        AND S.Fecha=E.Fecha AND S.Num=E.Num+1
    WHERE E.Num % 2 = 1  
    and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), e.FechaHoras, 103)='12/06/2021'
    GROUP BY E.Fecha, E
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Te toca [edit] la pregunta y anadir la estructura de las tablas que quieres usar y el resultado esperado, porque no sabemos qué quieres que pase :)

Comment: No sabemos qué es lo que no está funcionando en tu query, porque no sabemos lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Que tiene que ver esta consulta con la que estas tratando de hacer? eso es un select.. que tiene que ver con tu update?

Comment: Ya tienes un JOIN ahí ¿Por qué no lo tomas de ejemplo para hacer otro?